# RKConnectionDescription only works sometimes with Restkit 0.20.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to update multiple models during one GET request with RestKit using the shared manager, eg:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

where `responseDescriptor` has a mapping, key path, and path pattern.

The JSON being fetched has five separate models included in it and when starting from an empty application can be sizable, say 300 total objects (of different types).  Here's an edited example showing the general structure.  Things look like that, but there's more in the app.

```
{
"rooms":[{"id":1,"name":"Hall A"},{"id":2,"name":"Hall B"}],
"sessions":[{"id":168,"title":"Pre-emptive value-added strategy","room_id":1}]
}
```

In one mapping I'm trying to use `RKConnectonDescription` so that CoreData knows they are related based off of foreign keys.  For example:

```
    NSRelationshipDescription *roomRelationship = [_sessionMapping.entity relationshipsByName][@"room"];
    [_sessionMapping addConnection:[[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:roomRelationship attributes:@{ @"roomRemoteId": @"remoteId" }]];
```

All of the CoreData objects use a remoteId property as the identification attribute for the id that comes via json.  For example, the Session mapping looks like this:

```
    _sessionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];
    _sessionMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"remoteId" ];
    [_sessionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id" : @"remoteId",
     @"title": @"title",
     @"room_id": @"roomRemoteId"}];
```

and the room mapping looks like this:

```
    _roomMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Room" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];
    _roomMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"remoteId" ];
    [_roomMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id" : @"remoteId",
     @"name": @"name"
     }];
```

What I've found is that when I start from an empty database and fetch all of the objects, that only some of the sessions have rooms.  The Session model does have a `roomRemoteId` field and the rooms do have a `remoteId`.  I spot checked one of the sessions without a room and it did have a `roomRemoteId` set and I could look up a room with that `remoteId` in the database.

I'd estimate that about 25% of the sessions look fine, but the other 75% have a `roomRemoteId` but no room relation set.

So the question is, why do some sessions map correctly and others do not?

Comment: So you make a single call and all of the data for both types of item is in that one response? Can you include a copy of the JSON?

Comment: Good idea, I added a sample to illustrate

Comment: In your connection on the mapping, both attributes have 'remote' in the name. Usually it would be 'remote : identity' where 'identity' was the unique and persistent identifier and 'remote' is the transient just used to make the connection during mapping. What is the mapping for each of the objects?

Comment: Yes, I generally prepend remote to note that it is a key from the data source.  I've updated the question to include the mappings.  It may be something I've done in the setup, but I've been assuming it is something else because some of the sessions import just fine.

Comment: Can't see anything obvious wrong with your details above. Try turning on trace logging for the mapping and see if that offers any clues: RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wain for the good suggestions! After bumping the global Restkit log level up to trace I noticed that I had an inverse relationship on Room for `sessions` - but that I had spaced it and not made it one to many.  There were a lot of log entries that looked like this:

```
D restkit.core_data:RKRelationshipConnectionOperation.m:198 Connected relationship 'room' to object '<Room: 0x96fad00> (entity: Room; id: 0x1082e150 <x-coredata:///Room/t3B6287B3-4478-4B64-9D83-9C85387C377D629> ; data: {
    name = 2204;
    remoteId = 24;
    sessions = "0x1081b320 <x-coredata:///Session/t3B6287B3-4478-4B64-9D83-9C85387C377D233>";
})'
```

but nothing had more than one session in it.  That was my clue that I didn't have the relationships set up correctly and that kept the mapping from working completely.  Once I fixed that everything worked as expected.

Here's a screenshot of the properties for the sessions relationship, once I checked off the To-Many Relationship box it worked properly:

[image: XCode properties sheet for Core Data relationships]